# Woocommerce как получить список атрибутов в Single-product.php?

Tags: woocommerce

В файле content-product.php вывожу атрибуты следующим образом

```
global $product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
```

В файл single-product а именно content-single-product такой способ не работает. Каким образом можно получить атрибуты на странице продукта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что на этой странице в $product не содержится объект атрибута (не знаю почему), только его название, можете написать var_dump($product) и посмотреть что в нем.
Вы можете получить продукт и его атрибуты след образом:

```
$prod = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
$attr = $prod->get_attributes();
```